# Compilation failed for data model at path - xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode6

In one of my project, I am using CoreData to store all local data and it was working absolutely fine till xcode 5.1.1. But with the upgrade to xcode 6, I started getting compilation error. The error looks like this:

> /Users//Desktop/test/test/test.xcdatamodeld: Compilation failed
>   for data model at path
>   '/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-bheksmasmjewxsejmxeyasvvhrer/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/test.momd/test.mom'

I tried searching SO for the issue, found some suggestions and implemented them in my project as well. But none of the suggestions worked for me and am left wondering "what the h**l this issue is. Any hint/suggestion/solution will be a great help right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you ever resolved this issue, but I had the same issue after I erroneously versioned my data model. I found the steps below fixed my issue:

In Xcode locate your .xcdatamodeld file then click "Show in Finder" and delete the .xcdatamodel file that was not previously visible in Xcode or that was erroneously versioned.

Hope this helps you in some way, if you are still looking for answers.

Comment: I added a data model version and then changed my mind and rolled back git. After that, I experienced the same sort of compilation error. The solution by @GatorClos fixed it.

Comment: @GatorClos solution followed by deleting the Derived Data dir helped me.

Comment: Basically delete the previous .xcdatamodel file and create a new file at the same path with the same name and with the extension .xcdatamodel.